# Value of type 'PodPost' has no member 'episode'

Tags: json, swift, sub-array

***Also don't understand why the downvotes***

So the following code is saying it has no member of episode which is correct because the JSON gets passed to `PodEpisode` first. Then need to pass it to the last subarray

```
struct PodPost: Codable {
    var programs: [PodEpisode]
}

struct PodEpisode: Codable {
    var episode : [PodProgram]
}

struct PodProgram: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var title : String
    var enclosureurl : String
    var summary : String
}
```

I am calling it via

```
func getPodcast(podurl:String,completion: @escaping ([PodProgram]) -> ()) {
     
     
       let podurl = podurl
    
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://api.drn1.com.au/api-access/programs/\(podurl)") else { return }
           
           URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, _, _) in
               // Based on the updated structs, you would no
               // longer be decoding an array
               let podcast = try! JSONDecoder().decode(PodPost.self, from: data!)
            
                
               DispatchQueue.main.async{
                   // The array is stored under programs now
                completion(podcast.episode). // THIS IS THE LINE THAT ERROR SHOWS (Value of type 'PodPost' has no member 'episode' )
               }
               
           }
   }
```

I have tried the following

adding a

```
let episode = podcast.programs
then using that to call episode.episode // With no success.
```

[image: Pic of error]

[image]

Comment: Why did you delete your previous question just to post it again? And is it so hard to figure out how to solve this given the help I gave you in the comments in that deleted question?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
let podcast = try! JSONDecoder().decode(PodPost.self, from: data!)
```

Would give you an object of PodEpisode with property as *programs*

Now in the completion block you are trying to call *podcast.programs.episode* which isn't possible as its an array

If you need an episode you would need to do something like this

let episode = podcast.programs.first!.episode

Comment: what if I need to return all the epsiodes as they will get put in a list view - Also just updated the question with a pic of the error.